# React Native Slider styling issues (with code and image)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the react native's Slider in the center, with two images on left and right. However, when I put the style flexDirection: 'row' on the parent, it messes up the slider.

Desired Result:
[image]

Actual Result:
[image]

Actual Result with flexDirection: 'row' on View:
[image]

```
  <Content>
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 10 }}>
      <Image source={Images.quiet} />
      <Slider
        style={{ flex: 0 }}
        maximumValue={10}
        minimumValue={1}
        step={1}
        value={device.volume}
        minimumTrackTintColor={'#D05B35'}
        maximumTrackTintColor={'#D8D8D8'}
        thumbImage={Images.thumb}
        onSlidingComplete={(vol) => this.changeVolume(vol)}
        />
      <Image source={Images.loud} />
    </View>
  </Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by setting a width to slider